# .net standard x509 operating system differences

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, .net-standard

I have a DLL which creates a signature based off a JSON.
 The signing is used with X509 self signed certificate with a public \ private keys (.crt and .pfx files), the DLL is using the private key (pfx file) to sign the data.
This DLL is used twice: once in my actual project, which runs on a linux container, and once in my local tests project, which runs on my windows machine.
There is a second DLL uses the public key to verify the signature (crt file).
Here's the thing: the signature created in my test project matches the signature created in my verifier project, both are windows machines. The project on the linux machine signs differently.
What is going on here?? I have several directions:

1. Different newlines between linux and windows: I have changed the signing DLL so that it takes the JSON string, deserializes into Newtonsoft.JSON object, serializes again with flag *Formatting.None*, and then deserializes for the final time. This did not help.
2. Different invisible characters \ encoding: my code is calling UTF8.GetBytes internally on the string, so don't think it's that.
3. Additionaly, I took the literall byte array from the linux machine into the windows machine, and got different signatures.
4. Which leads me to think, is the library System.Security.Cryptography.Xml(5.0.0) behaves differently between the OSs? [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#x509-certificates) says yes, but does not say how:

> Cryptographic operations in .NET Core and .NET 5 are done by operating system (OS) libraries. This dependency has advantages

Any ideas as to why this is happening, and maybe a solution?
My signer code:

```
...
JToken data = JToken.Parse("{}") //obviously a different string
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(...);
var rsaCSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaCSP.FromXmlString(certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
var signatureBytes = rsaCSP.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString(), CryptoConfig.MapNameToIOD(...));
```

Comment: Just print out the contents of the strings hex-encoded and compare.

Comment: as I mentioned in #3, I did, and they are the same